# Goland IDE - offline usage

Tags: goland

In GoLand -> Licenses I have configured "Activate GoLand" -> License server and I entered the provided by my company server (https://jetbrains.my_company.com/).

This is fine when I am at work.

At home, however, this site is not reachable. It says it cannot fetch the license and the only opportunity it gives me is to exit the IDE.
Does this mean I cannot work offline in GoLand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JetBrains has a help page on how to work offline and to optimize your environment up for online usage. You can find it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/working-offline.html).

You can find more information on how to generate the code [here](https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb/articles/206544099-How-will-this-change-affect-customers-in-Government-Education-and-others-who-are-unable-to-utilize-electronic-delivery-or-web-accessed-software-). I've pasted the relevant info below.

> After purchase, within our portal, you will have the option to either connect via your JetBrains Account or to generate an offline activation code to use during your subscription term.